# VueJS: How to call a variable from string instead of direct variable name in a template?

Tags: vue.js

How to call a variable set in `<script>` from the template using its string name?

For instance, in the example below, I'd like to call the `foo` variable using `table[0]`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ table[0] }}
    {{ table[1] }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      foo: 'Hello World!',
      bar: '大家好!',
      table: ['foo', 'bar']
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using `$data`, like `{{ $data[table[0]] }}`